# wxpython + matplotlib: closing figure hangs python

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

This python program plots a figure in a wxpython window. It runs fine in Enthought Python Distribution 7.3-2, but when I close the figure, python keeps running and doesn't exit.

What am I missing? When I create wxpython GUIs that don't use matplotlib, they exit correctly after I close the window. I guess there must be something about message loops in wxpython that I don't understand.

```
# adapted from:
# http://wiki.wxpython.org/Getting%20Started
# http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~kena/classes/5448/s11/presentations/pearse.pdf

import wx
import pylab as pl
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas

class GUIPanel(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent

        # create some sizers
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        # A button
        self.button =wx.Button(self, label="Tada!")
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClick,self.button)

        # put up a figure
        self.figure = pl.figure()
        self.axes = self.drawplot(self.figure)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)

        sizer.Add(self.canvas, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL)
        sizer.Add(self.button, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL)

        self.SetSizerAndFit(sizer)  
    def log(self, fmt, *args):
        print (fmt % args)
    def OnClick(self,event):
        self.log("button clicked, id#%d\n", event.GetId())
    def drawplot(self, fig):
        ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
        t = pl.arange(0,1,0.001)
        ax.plot(t,t*t)
        ax.grid()
        return ax

app = wx.App(False)
frame = wx.Frame(None)
panel = GUIPanel(frame)
frame.Fit()
frame.Center()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/.  It looks like you are creating figures using pylab, which has it's own event loop which is what is messing you up.

Comment: pylab has an event loop that's different from matplotlib? ick.

Comment: no it is an event loop that is separate from the one you start in `app.MainLoop`.  pylab _is_ matplotlib, just with a bit of magic on top.

Comment: Where is the functionality of the "magic" documented? I'm uncomfortable with the idea that pylab is the same functions and same interface as matplotlib, yet does something different that I don't know about.

Comment: ...or should I just change from `pl.figure()` to `matplotlib.figure()`

Comment: pyplot/pylab api: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html .  The primary thing it adds is state-machine like behavior so you can use it like MATLAB.  Most of it's functions figure out what you current axes is, and then call the correct function on that axes.

Comment: ah, ok. I hate that state machine behavior stuff in MATLAB. It's too implicit. Thanks for the pointers, I think I've solved this problem.

Comment: The nice thing about matplotlib is that the state machine is built on top of the OO, so you can ignore it if you want to.

Comment: yeah, I started learning matplotlib just because MATLAB access was inconvenient (we only have 1 license on a laptop) and it integrated well with Python. Now I'm starting to like it better for some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Huh. Per the discussion in comments from tcaswell, I changed

```
self.figure = pl.figure()
```

to

```
self.figure = matplotlib.figure.Figure()
```

and it fixed the problem. (python exits when I close the window)

Comment: `pl.figure()` creates a `matplotlib.figure.Figure()` instance + sets up a gui object to handle it.  That extra functionality is super nice when you are playing around with plots interactively, but can mess you up if you are embedding or doing stuff programatically.